# I do not have a menu folder in my Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I do not have a menu folder in my Project

[image]

Comment: So, create one. Right-click over `res/` and choose "New > Directory" or "New > Android resource directory".

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bz5l5_kQy0&list=PLyfVjOYzujujmyOIPkoA8uRs85ue8SmAG&index=1 10:50 minutes  In this video, there is a menu folder

Comment: "10:50 minutes In this video, there is a menu folder" -- apparently, you are not using the same versions of the tools as are shown in that video. The directories and files created by the new-project and new-activity wizards are based on templates, and those templates change over time.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Android Studio doesn't create folders like "libs" and "menu", so you just need to create it yourself, like @CommonsWare said. Android Studio will recognize the folders you created.